# CHM file not displaying at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, chm

I have a weird bug.  When I am debugging a C# Winform application and I select the help button from the menu, I can see the help file (chm file) fine.  It displays in its own popup window.  But when I install the application and then hit the same button, the help file does not show up at all.

What could be causing this?

Edit:  I have also tried changing the "Build Action" on the .chm file to "Content" and then to "Embedded Resource", but those did not make a difference.

Comment: How are you opening the CHM file?  Did you make sure it isn't "blocked"?  (If not, check here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902225 )

Comment: No window or no content?

Comment: Sorry, no window shows up at all.